# Kaby Lake i5 or Coffee Lake i3

Tags: processor

I'm about to embark on my 1st self build and want to spec a machine for general home use to include for general office duties, hobby photo editing using elements, organising my music collection and perhaps some light gaming. I had been planning to use a Kaby Lake i5 processor but I wonder if my needs, and some better degree of longevity would be better served by using a Coffee Lake i3 chip? I can't stretch to a Coffee Lake i5.

Comment: Would motherboard also be a consideration? Would you consider going with the Coffee Lake i3 and then upgrading to an i5 in the next year or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's 8350K vs 7600K, I would go for the 8350K, as it is slightly cheaper and a little better performing.

Even 8100 vs 7400 shows the same scenario.